# Unable to read values from application.yaml when running unit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Class called Profile which reads the first Name and Last Name from application.yaml and prints the full name using the static print() method. Here is the code:

```
@Component
public final class Profile {

private static final String NAME = "config.firstName";
private static final String LAST_NAME = "config.lastName";

private static String name;
private static String lastName;


    public Profile(
       @Value("${" + NAME + "}") final String name,
       @Value("${" + LAST_NAME + "}") final String lastName) {

       Profile.name = notNull(name);
       Profile.lastName = notNull(lastName);
    }

    public static String print() {
       return name + " " + lastName;

    }
}
```

I have a written a unit test to test this, here is the code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class PrintTest {

   @Test
   public void testPrint() {
      String fullName = Hello.print();
      assertEquals("John Smith", fullName);
   }
}
```

When I run the unit Test, I get **"null null"** instead of **John Smith**.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: And why should it... You have a class outside the scope of Spring and you expect it to get automagically be injected with values. You have at least to configure the instance with spring and use the Spring managed instance.

Answer (score 0):

Profile is a Spring Component, ApplicationContext initializes the bean for you. Your test class should look like this,

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations= "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.yaml")
public class PrintTest {
@Autowired
private Profile profile;

   @Test
   public void testPrint() {
      String fullName = profile.print();
      assertEquals("John Smith", fullName);
   }

}
```

The application.yaml should be available in classpath, if yours is a Maven project, then place your application.yaml in src/test/resources folder.